# Spring Cloud Stream topic per message for different consumers

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

The topology I am looking for is

[image]

So far I have not seen a way to define the topic per message in Cloud Stream. I understand that the consumers will be bound to specific topic but how does the producer sets the topic per message before sending the message to the exchange?

```
source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(myMessage).build());
```

Does not provide any way to set the topic for the exchange to route to the proper consumer.

Or maybe I don't understand something correctly?

**UPDATE**

I would expect not to receive the message in the consumer due to the `bindingRoutingKey` being `2222` and I am sending with `routeTo` `1111`. But I still receive it on the consumer.

Producer Properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=messageExchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routeTo']


@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

Sender:

`source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(mo).setHeader("routeTo", "1111").build());`

And the Consumer:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=messageExchange
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=2222
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void ReceiveMo(String moDTO) {
    log.info("Message received moDTO: {}", moDTO);
}

}
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

With the suggestions in the accepted answer below. I was able to make it work. Needed to remove the exchanges and queues from RabbitMQ using its UI and restart the RabbitMQ docker image.

Comment: the same i was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the `routingKeyExpression` [rabbitmq producer property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_rabbit_producer_properties).

e.g. `...producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routeTo']`

then

```
source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(myMessage)
    .setHeader("routeTo", "Booking.new")
    .build());
```

Note that the destination is the exchange name. By default, the binder expects a `Topic` exchange. If you wish to use a Direct exchange instead, you must set the `exchangeType` property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using a Topic exchange would work ok I guess (I just could not find a nice image). By the way, one the consumer side I could use a comma separated routinKeyExpression like Booking.new.*, Orders.# . Is this correct?

Comment: On the consumer side, the property is `bindingRoutingKey` and, no, the binder only supports binding with a single key. If you need something more exotic you would need to add the additional queue/exchange bindings yourself.

Comment: I tried using the header `routeTo` with the `bindingRoutingKey` set to the consumer but it does not seem to work. I update the question. I would really appreciate it if you could point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the bindings on the console? Did you remove the old (default) binding `#`?

Comment: You are right!!! I needed to remove the exchange/queues from the rabbitMQ and restart it. Now it is working as expected. One more thing was that I had not added the producer.routing-key-epxression correctly. Still both this and the bindingRoutingKey Eclipse tells me that are unkown although I can see them in the documentation. But at least it works! Thank you again.