# Spring Cloud Stream topic per message for different consumers (in one Comsumer app)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

This question is similar to [Spring Cloud Stream topic per message for different consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190785/spring-cloud-stream-topic-per-message-for-different-consumers)  but the difference is that I want multiple Sinks in one consumer springboot application and I want to do this by rabbitmq topic(which is by default in spring cloud stream). I am not able to figure out correct configuration or somethign wrong in code. I have 3  sinks/cosumers. consumer1 is default and every message goes there.

**Updated as suggested by Garry **

Comment: my Producer App has routing key='*.events'
application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: my-exchange
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          output:
            producer:
              routing-key-expression: headers['*.events']
  application:
    name: publisher-service
server:
  port: 15010
```

**Producer code snippet** 
Comment:message is sent with routing key ="test.events" . I sm not sure of 2nd argument but i am assuming it is bindingrouting-key =test1.events.billing which means I want it to be delivered to billing consumer besides default consumer.

```
 source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(eventRequest.getEventMessage())
                    .setHeader("*.events", "test1.events.billing")
                    .build());
```

Consumer configuration
Comment: I want 3 queues assigned to exchange ="myexchange" . I am not sure if config is right.
application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
      stream:
        bindings:
          defaultconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue1
          billingconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue2
          messageconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue3

        rabbit:
          bindings:
            defaultconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: '*.events.#'
            billingconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: test1.events.billing
            messageconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: test2.events.messages

  application:
    name: subscriber-service
server:
  port: 15020
```

Consumer code:
IEventConsumer.java
Comment: I am not sure the code below is right

```
public interface IEventConsumer {
     String INPUT = "my-exchange";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel defaultconsumer();

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel billingconsumer();

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel messageconsumer();
}
```

EventConsumer.java
Comment: All Iwant from below is the message should not be received my messsageConsumer!
But in reality it goes thru all  these methods.

```
    @StreamListener("defaultconsumer")
    public void subscribe1(EventMessage eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" DefaultEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }


   @StreamListener("billingconsumer")
    public void subscribe2(EventMessage eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" billingEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @StreamListener("messageconsumer")
    public void subscribe3(EventMessage eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" messageEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }
```

Apparently something is wrong above and I dont see this working .Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel defaultconsumer();

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel billingconsumer();

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel messageconsumer();
```

You are giving all three bindings the same name; just use `@INPUT` and the method name will be used as the binding name.

And

```
@StreamListener("defaultconsumer")
```

etc.

**EDIT**

I just copied your code and it worked fine...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding({ IEventConsumer.class, Source.class })
public class So60879187Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So60879187Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60879187Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener("defaultconsumer")
    public void subscribe1(String eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" DefaultEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @StreamListener("billingconsumer")
    public void subscribe2(String eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" billingEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @StreamListener("messageconsumer")
    public void subscribe3(String eventMessage) {
        logger.info(" messageEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                .setHeader("*.events", "test1.events.billing")
                .build());
    }

}

interface IEventConsumer {
    String INPUT = "my-exchange";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel defaultconsumer();

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel billingconsumer();

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel messageconsumer();

}
```

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
      stream:
        bindings:
          defaultconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue1
          billingconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue2
          messageconsumer:
            destination: my-exchange
            group: queue3
          output:
            destination: my-exchange

        rabbit:
          bindings:
            defaultconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: '*.events.#'
            billingconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: test1.events.billing
            messageconsumer:
              consumer:
                bindingRoutingKey: test2.events.messages
            output:
              producer:
                routing-key-expression: headers['*.events']

  application:
    name: subscriber-service
server:
  port: 15020
```

and

```
2020-03-27 09:45:33.607  INFO 30366 --- [change.queue1-1] com.example.demo.So60879187Application   
  :  DefaultEventConsumer received new event [foo] 
2020-03-27 09:45:33.607  INFO 30366 --- [change.queue2-1] com.example.demo.So60879187Application   
  :  billingEventConsumer received new event [foo]
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

Newer functional programming model equivalent...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So608791871Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So608791871Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So608791871Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> defaultconsumer() {
        return eventMessage ->
                logger.info(" DefaultEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> billingconsumer() {
        return eventMessage ->
                logger.info(" billingEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> messageconsumer() {
        return eventMessage ->
                logger.info(" messageEventConsumer received new event [" + eventMessage.toString() + "] ");
    }

    private final DirectProcessor<Message<?>> output = DirectProcessor.create();

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<?>>> output() {
        return () -> this.output;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        Message<String> msg1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                .setHeader("*.events", "test1.events.billing")
                .build();
        Message<String> msg2 = MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar")
                .setHeader("*.events", "test2.events.messages")
                .build();
        return args -> {
            this.output.onNext(msg1);
            this.output.onNext(msg2);
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: defaultconsumer;billingconsumer;messageconsumer;output
    stream:
      bindings:
        defaultconsumer-in-0:
          destination: my-exchange
          group: queue1
        billingconsumer-in-0:
          destination: my-exchange
          group: queue2
        messageconsumer-in-0:
          destination: my-exchange
          group: queue3
        output-out-0:
          destination: my-exchange

      rabbit:
        bindings:
          defaultconsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: '*.events.#'
          billingconsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: test1.events.billing
          messageconsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: test2.events.messages
          output-out-0:
            producer:
              routing-key-expression: headers['*.events']

  application:
    name: subscriber-service
server:
  port: 15020
```

and

```
2020-03-27 14:28:37.426  INFO 3646 --- [change.queue3-1] com.example.demo.So608791871Application
  :  messageEventConsumer received new event [bar] 
2020-03-27 14:28:37.426  INFO 3646 --- [change.queue1-1] com.example.demo.So608791871Application
  :  DefaultEventConsumer received new event [foo] 
2020-03-27 14:28:37.426  INFO 3646 --- [change.queue2-1] com.example.demo.So608791871Application
  :  billingEventConsumer received new event [foo] 
2020-03-27 14:28:37.429  INFO 3646 --- [change.queue1-1] com.example.demo.So608791871Application
  :  DefaultEventConsumer received new event [bar]
```

Comment: I updated (please see above). Now the message is not even arriving and In rabbitmq console, I now see 4 exchanges : 1 from producer myexchange(no bindings i) and other 3 are defaultconsumer,messageconsumer and billingconsumer.The consumer exchanges have bindings like defaultconsumer.anonymous.VZ94MTkTSaaDPLXuhtgcIA etc. for each ones. I think binding config is wrong. not able to figure out.

Comment: Anonymous bindings mean that the `group` property is not being applied for some reason.

Comment: I just copied your code and configuration and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thnx,Garry for our time .I need to look closely what silly mistake I am doing.

Comment: Once I get it fixed, i will update the post and then accept

Comment: I updated my example to use the newer functional programming model.

Comment: Thank you very much, Garry. 
The issue with earlier one was there was mismatch in config and code for consumer channels in my real app . If you do that, those get registered as Exchange without bindings-not sure why. And so consumer was not receiving.